# Application Server was not connected before run configuration stop

Tags: java, spring-boot, networking

I am using Intellij Ultimate edition 18.2.7

Working on a Java project using Maven as my build tool.

I am getting this error when attempting to launch my project via Jetty server.

Error-

> Application Server was not connected before run configuration stop,
> reason: java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host:
> 192.168.188.195; nested exception is: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect"

Have attempted, to update the liquibse, maven, and service files, rebuild the project in IntelliJ, open and shut down IntelliJ, restart the system

Comment: Are you sure Intellij is the problem? You could start your app from the terminal with a JAR or Maven command

Comment: Have you found an answer to this?I am having same issue in version 2021.2.3

Comment: yes, its a firewall issue, just off your firewall and try to run , it will work